# Chaining multiple OR's onto a WHERE clause with Node and DB2

Tags: sql, node.js, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to build a basic filtering component where users will select manufactures from a list to filter by. Any one that's selected would have to be an additional OR on the WHERE clause in my SQL statement. The tech stack is Vue and Node with DB2 running on a AS/400.

I've seen libraries where you can build queries, but none that work for db2. What options do I have here? Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish with the Knex.js library that does not support DB2.

*Knex.js is a "batteries included" SQL query builder for Postgres, MSSQL, MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite3, Oracle, and Amazon Redshift*

```
knex('users').where(function() {
  this.where('id', 1).orWhere('id', '>', 10)
}).orWhere({name: 'Tester'})
Outputs:
select * from `users` where (`id` = 1 or `id` > 10) or (`name` = 'Tester')
```

Comment: You'll need to demonstrate how exactly "libraries where you can build queries" do not "work for db2" if you want a meaningful answer, otherwise -- use libraries that do work with Db2. And by the way, a single `select` can only have _one_ `where` clause.

Comment: I know this is a novel concept in today's environment, but instead of using a library to build your SQL statement, maybe just write the SQL?

Comment: I have no problem writing raw SQL if I didn't think it was dangerous. I just don't want to create any security flaws using string replacement or another sort of method to build dynamic queries.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Have you built dynamic queries based off user input before on the AS/400 that were secure from SQL injection attacks? Is so, I'd like to know how as it's proving to be rather difficult.

Comment: Yes, use prepared queries with parameter replacement. Don't just concatenate user input into the command string.

Comment: What if you don't know how many parameters you will be passing in? This is the problem and why I mentioned it was a filtering component. The user could filter by one filter or 25 filters, it won't always be the same where a nice prepared statement would work.

Comment: I use RPG rather than node, but if I don't know the number of parameter markers, I use an SQL descriptor to provide the parameters, and load the descriptor as I build the statement. The last step in loading the descriptor is telling how many parameters were loaded.

Comment: Unfortunately, the SQL I use to access the descriptor in RPG is different that you would use for some other language as it is not an SQL Statement, but a preprocessor directive that must be embedded in a HLL like RPG, or COBOL. Not sure how that would work in javascript.

Comment: You could try [node-jt400](https://github.com/tryggingamidstodin/node-jt400#promises) which looks like it can handle varying numbers of parameters with a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

The query generated by your library is syntactically incorrect for Db2 -- it uses backticks to quote identifiers, which is not standard and used only by MySQL, as far as I know. Apparently the library does not support Db2 natively, but you could try configuring it to use the Postgres dialect, which is closer to the SQL standard and as such is more likely to produce statements that Db2 will understand. Better yet, as I suggested in a comment, find a library that supports Db2 natively.

Comment: I used that libraries example purely to show what I was trying to accomplish. As far as I know there aren't any query building libraries for Node/Db2 that are supported.